# Problems with wamp configuration after installation

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I recently installed wamp2.5 and I am having a series of problems with it.

1. I get the error "Access denied for user: 'dante ' @ ' @ localhost' (password : YES )"
   (think the first issue here is why there are two @ signs)
2. When i try to click on a web project on my localhost interface, instead of the url leading to, for example, localhost/mysite ... it instead points to www.mysite.com

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: See [this post for how to configure Apache correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) with Virtual Hosts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second issue you can go to `wamp/www/index.php`.

And change:

```
$suppress_localhost = true;
```

To :

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

I'll see what I can do about the first problem.

Comment: This is a quick fix that will potentially lead to problems moving projects to a LIVE server. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) for a better more realiable solution using Virtual Hosts

Answer (score 1):

By default WAMPServer like most MYSQL deliveries comes with only one account set in MYSQL.

This is `root` and comes out of the box with no password set.

So to login to phpMyAdmin for example you should use :

```
Username = root
Password = (leave it blank)
```

As to your second point, you should consider setting up Virtual Hosts in Apache for all your projects. See [this post for how to configure Apache correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) with Virtual Hosts